# Structure order of an array based on an item in the array has certain value set to true

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I have incoming data from my CMS that all contains the value `featuredProject`, it can be true, null or false. If it's true I add a css class that makes it span across the screen. To help keep my grid structure intact I need to always have at least two projects with `featuredProject` set to false or null before or after a project with `featuredProject` set to true.

The problem is that the data from the CMS doesn't respect the supposed design of the grid and can and probably will come out distorted from what I need to loop it out correctly.

What I've been trying to achive now is a function that loops over all projects in the array from the CMS and looks at what the `featuredProject` value is on the current project in the loop. If it's set to true I look back at the past 2 indexes of the array to see what their `featuredProject` value is. If both of them doesn't have the value set to false or null I want to sort the array by shifting the current index one step forward, exit the loop and then loop over it again to check if all the values are in order.

Right now I get an error where one value of the array is `undefined` which I don't really get why.

An image displaying the grid I would like to achieve.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9WXg.jpg

The code I have right now.

The function to move an index

```
function move(array: any[], from: number, to: number) {
    if (to === from) return array

    const target = array[from]
    const increment = to < from ? -1 : 1

    for (let k = from; k != to; k += increment) {
        array[k] = array[k + increment]
    }
    array[to] = target
    return array
}
```

The function that checks the value of `featuredProject`

```
const sortImageGrid = (arr: any[]): any[] => {
    // console.log(arr)

    const sortedArr: any[] = []
    arr.map((item, index) => {
        if (item === undefined) {
            return
        }
        // console.log(item)
        if (index === 0) {
            sortedArr.push(item)
        } else if (index === 1 && item.featuredProject) {
            move(arr, index, index + 1)
        } else if (index === 1 && !item.featuredProject) {
            sortedArr.push(item)
        } else if (
            item.featuredProject &&
            !arr[index - 1].featuredProject &&
            !arr[index - 2].featuredProject
        ) {
            sortedArr.push(item)
        } else if (
            (item.featuredProject && arr[index - 1].featuredProject === true) ||
            (item.featuredProject && arr[index - 2].featuredProject === true)
        ) {
            move(arr, index, index + 1)
        } else {
            sortedArr.push(item)
        }
        console.log(sortedArr)
    })
    if (sortedArr.length === arr.length) {
        return sortedArr
    } else {
        return []
    }
}
```

How I run the function in the component where I map out the projects

```
    const [gridSorted, setGridSorted] = useState(false)
    let sortedArr: any[] = []

    if (data.allSanityProject.nodes && data.allSanityProject.nodes.length > 0) {
        while (gridSorted === false) {
            sortedArr = sortImageGrid(data.allSanityProject.nodes)
            // console.log(sortedArr)
            if (sortedArr.length === data.allSanityProject.nodes.length) {
                setGridSorted(true)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I'm thinking you could do this is filter out the responses into separate arrays:

```
let falsyValues = [];
let truthyValues = []
for(let item of arr){
    if(item.featuredProject){
        truthyValues.push(item)
    } else {
        falsyValues.push(item)
    }
}
```

Then create a function that "zips" them based on your criteria:

```
function zip(falsyArr, truthyArr){
    let zippedValues = []
    for(let i = 0, n = 0; i < falsyArr.length; i++, n += 2){
        if(!falsyArr[n] || !falsyArr[n+1]){
            return zippedValues
        }
        zippedValues.push(falsyArr[n], falsyArry[n+1], truthyArr[i])
    }
    return zippedValues;
}
```

You'll just have to slightly adjust the `zip` function to account for arrays with differing lengths and determine which one you want to loop over (probably the max length between the two).

Comment: This could work. But as I stated I do need at least two `falsyValues` to be next to each other in the `zippedValues` array. It could be more than two but they need to come in pairs. Example `[truthy, falsy, falsy, truthy, falsy, falsy, falsy, falsy,truhty]`

Comment: @MattiasRådemar I just edited it, try something like that out. I haven't tested it so you will have to tweak it a bit. Also you'll most likely need to include some more sad path conditions.

Comment: Yes your edited solution seems to mostly do the trick. Only need to change it so I can get a single falsyValue if its at the bottom. Thank you mate!

Comment: @MattiasRådemar No problem, hopefully it gets you to where you want to be!